# How do I install Ubuntu minimal inside windows using Wubi?

Tags: wubi, ubuntu-minimal

I believe in making my own Ubuntu hence always use Ubuntu-minimal as the base install.
Afterward, I follow `apt-get` to install whatever packages I want.
I like it being minimal.

This time I want to have an install inside Windows 7 using Wubi.
<strike>How do I install Ubuntu-Minimal with Wubi; inside Windows xp or 7?</strike>

EDIT:
But I am aware that it's not [directly possible](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide/#DVD_and_Alternate_ISO) to use Wubi for minimal alternate install.

**I want to know how should wubi be modified so that it works with alternate install?**

**Is there any alternative to wubi which works for alternate installer?**

Comment: This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable see the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq#close)